# How to persist a solution with projects and documents using Roslyn's AdhocWorkspace?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've been trying to persist a new solution containing a project and a simple cs file with the following code but nothing get saved to the disk. Am I doing something wrong or is Roslyn not the tool to be used to generate solutions project and files?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();

        var solutionInfo = SolutionInfo.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId(),
                                               VersionStamp.Create(),
                                               @"C:\Seb\SebSol.sln");

        var projectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(),
                                             VersionStamp.Create(),
                                             "SebProj",
                                             "SebProj.dll",
                                             LanguageNames.CSharp,
                                             @"C:\Seb\SebSol\SebProj\SebProj.csproj");

        workspace.AddSolution(solutionInfo);
        workspace.AddProject(projectInfo);

        var sourceText = SourceText.From("public class A { }");
        workspace.CurrentSolution.AddDocument(DocumentId.CreateNewId(projectInfo.Id), "ClassA.cs", sourceText);

        workspace.TryApplyChanges(workspace.CurrentSolution);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `MsBuildWorkspace`, which can actually update `sln` and `csproj` files in MSBuild format on disk.

Other than that class, Roslyn APIs are completely agnostic to project formats such as MSBuild.